# $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-(-1)^n)n^{((-1)^n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-(-1)^n)n^{((-1)^n)}$$  $$n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Any idea how to evaluate this limit?

I noticed that $$(1-(-1)^n)$$ is between 2 and 0 depending on the value of $n$.$$n^{((-1)^n)}$$ oscillates between being arbitrarily large and zero as $n\to\infty$. This didn't lead to any conclusions though.

How can I evaluate this limit?

Comment: The subsequence $n=2k$ is the constant sequence $(0)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which tends to $0$. The subsequence $n=2k-1$ is the sequence $\left(\frac2{2k-1}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which tends to $0$. So the original sequence also tends to $0$.

Comment: 0 seems to be the correct answer, and lines up with what I have checked on Desmos

Comment: @Peter Foreman thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
2/n, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$ then
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{n} = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} 0 = 0$  so I concluded that limit is zero.I want to know if there is a mistake.